# iOS : Find all near by iOS device using bluetooth in specific region

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Here, I am developing one application which Find out all near by iOS device using bluetooth in given fixed specific region in other iOS devices have same application installed.

Is there any one who can guide me which way can I go and find all other device near to me?

Like, which frame work I should use and all...etc

I am looking for the way in which I can go ahead and accomplish this with quick connection.

Any suggestion will be great help to me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "specific region"? Your app has to advertise, being a `CBPeripheral`, and the other has to scan.

Comment: Sorry for confusion by "specific region" I mean in particular range of area for ex. 100 meter

Comment: Well, you have to emit and scan. That's all. But I think that an iDevice can't be a emitter and a receiver at the same time...

Comment: Yes, you can adopt a peripheral role and a central role at the same time.  You could also look at the multi peer framework - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks for suggestion, Is there any code sample which does the same thing with multi peer framework as you suggest.

Comment: @Larme: CoreBluetooth framework is good option for this task? or Multi peer framework as suggested by Paulw11? 

I have tried with corebluetooth framework with this flow: One device is act as central manager to receives data and other device advertising data using peripheral manager.

But not got success

Comment: The Multipeer framework is a higher level than Core Bluetooth, so it is probably easier to use.  The Multipeer framework will also use Wi Fi as well as Bluetooth, but you can't advertise/scan in the background like you can with Bluetooth Low Energy, so with Multipeer framework you will only find people who are running your app in the foreground at that moment

Comment: If you simply search Google for "multipeer framework example" you will find a number of web sites with sample applications/code

Comment: Well, people have to the app launched in foreground/background, while using a serveur/GPS, it could receive notifications. That could be interesting.